# Product compare list empty on costum module page

Tags: magento-1.7, product, module, product-list, compare

At header.phtml I load the product compare list with the following code:
`$collection = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_compare_list')->getItems();`
On default pages like category, product, cms pages the compare list is loaded.
But when I go to a custom module page (also on the frontend) the compare list is not loaded.
When I debug the $collection I noticed that _visitorId is different on the custom module page.
How can I load the compare list on the costum module page?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, I'm not sure if it is the correct way but it is working.
I'm using Alan Storms module to get the real visitor_id and I load this in to my collection
http://alanstorm.com/magento_cross_area_sessions

```
$frontend = Mage::getModel('pulsestorm_crossareasession/manager')->getSessionData('frontend'); 
$visitorid = $frontend['core']['visitor_data']['visitor_id'];

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_compare_item_collection')
            ->useProductItem(true)
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

$collection->setVisitorId( $visitorid );

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection($collection);
$collection->addPriceData();

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addUrlRewrite()
            ->load();
```